# Validação de TextBox em Visual Basic 6

Tags: validação, textbox, visual-basic-6

Como posso fazer uma validação no textbox para habilitar ou desabilitar um botão?
Esse é o código que fiz até agora.

```
   If IsNumeric(txtPedidoCotacao.text) Then
        cmdMontaPedido.enabled = True
        cmdCancelar.enabled = True
        CmdAutorizacao.enabled = True
        cmdConfiguraPaginas.enabled = True
        cmdCotacoes.enabled = True

        ElseIf KeyAscii = 8 Then
        cmdMontaPedido.enabled = False
        cmdCancelar.enabled = False
        CmdAutorizacao.enabled = False
        cmdConfiguraPaginas.enabled = False
        cmdCotacoes.enabled = False
```

OBS: O método está no KeyPress ( txtPedidoCotacao_KeyPress ).

Answer (score 1):

Teste desta forma com o método `txtPedidoCotacao_Change()`:

```
 Private Sub txtPedidoCotacao_Change()
        If IsNumeric(txtPedidoCotacao) Then
            cmdMontaPedido.Enabled = True
        Else
            cmdMontaPedido.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
```